# how to fix EventSource not defined error?

Tags: typescript, next.js, server-sent-events

I am working on adding `SSE Events` in my Next JS project. I have an URL for accessing SSE Events.

Here's the Code:

```
const ssEvents = new EventSource(stream_url,{withCredentials:false})
  
  ssEvents.addEventListener("participant.details", (e)=>{
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data)
    console.log(data)
  })
```

I am getting EventSouce not defined error. Since EventSource is a built in library in js. I can even access `.addEventListener` in it. But on Execution, it shows `EventSource not defined`. I don't know why its showing. Is there any thing I missed to add in my Code. Please help me with some solutions to fix this. The Code is in Typescript. Is I want to add any additional things.

Error Trace:

```
error - pages/index.tsx (55:19) @ Home
ReferenceError: EventSource is not defined

  54 | 
> 55 |   const ssEvents = new EventSource(stream_url,{withCredentials:false})
     |                   ^
  56 |
```

tsConfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "src/utils/analytics/index.js",
    "react-google-captcha.d.ts",
    "src/providers/apollo.tsx",
    "src/providers/apollo-client.ts",
    "src/utils/wallet/walletManager.js"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: you tagged `next` ... did you mean `next.js`?

Comment: Does it really say `EventSouce` not defined?  That might be evidence of a typo somewhere.

Comment: @JaromandaX, yes next js

Comment: @Wyck, i have checked, there is no typo. I have added Error Trace

Comment: Is this server-side code?  And if so, did you `require("eventsource");`

Comment: Is this the only occurrence of `EventSource` in your code? Nothing in the `import` section (eg `import { EventSource } from "somewhere"`)? Still waiting on that `tsconfig.json` file too

Comment: @Wyck, No. its a  Client Side

Comment: @Phil, EventSource is a built in right? I don't know, Is I want to download Library for that

Comment: `"target": "es5"` might be a little on the old side

Comment: @Phil, Is I can't EventSource in es5?

Comment: Is your TypeScript version at least 2.7?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If you do a global file search for `EventSource`, is `pages/index.tsx` the only result?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy, Yes Typescript version is 4.5

Comment: @Phil, Is I want to import eventSource library from where? Is its not a built in one?

Comment: Can you link to a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) reproducing the issue?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? It might be that you're trying to call `new EventSource(...)` when the app gets server-side rendered. Make sure you call it from inside a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is that NextJS on the backend side.

And `EventSource` does not exist on Node.

Please make sure your SSE code is only run on the browser.

Comment: how would you test this then? node.js lib seems to have an `EventSource`

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered problem like this too using Nuxt3 (not NextJS).
My solution is make the file that using it only rendered in client by adding the **client** tag (`<ClientOnly>` in Nuxt3).

But I think in NextJS you can add `'use client'` on top of that file.

References:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials